# How do I look for a word, which letters are seperated by spaces?

Tags: regex, grep, find, sed

I want to grep over pdf files for specific search terms. I'm using pdfgrep for this task, which works quite fine. However, sometimes words are specified with spaces between each letter. E.g.: `spacedword` is written as `s p a c e d w o r d`.

So I guess my question is: How do I look for a word, which letters are seperated by spaces?

Currently I am using a script to further process the search results:

```
search=$1
  

pdfgrep -i "$search" * | grep "$search" -i -B 1 | sed "s/-$//g" | sed "s/\s\+/;/g" > "$search".csv
```

I am lazy though and was thinking of a regex solution, that would search for `spacedword` and `s p a c e d w o r d` withouth the need of explicitly writing both of the search terms as two separate parameters.

There are no occurences of mixed spaced words and unspaced words. So there's only `spacedword` or `s p a c e d w o r d` within a pdf file (and nothing like `s pa c edw o rd`), I just don't know beforehand which version is within the pdf, without looking in there myself.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a shell question. It follows the same principle for all terminal programs.

You have to prefix spaces with a backslash: `s\ p\ a\ c\ e\ w\ o\ r\ d` 
Or wrap the entire thing in single quotes: `'s p a c e w o r d'` 
Or double quotes: `"s p a c e w o r d"`

The difference between single quotes and double quotes is that double quotes interpolate variables and other stuff, while single quotes are always literal.

(This answer applies to sh-like shells, including the ubiquitous bash. Other shells may work differently.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I reckon your answer is the quickest solution. I am lazy though and was thinking more of a regex solution, that would search for spacedword and s p a c e d w o r d withouth the need of explicitly writing both of the search terms as two separate parameters.

Comment: @Torsten How about `s pa c edw o rd`? Any requirement should be in the question body, not in comments.